# Not able to right click on anything on Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am not able to right click on Jmeter 2.11, getting the following error:

Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.

Can anyone help on this.

Thanx

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that users know it is usable. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Did you any plugin to JMeter? If Yes, remove that plugin and start the JMeter.

Following are some of the resources:

1. https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/jmeter-could-not-initialize-menufactory-class/
2. http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-after-starting-JMeter-with-custom-plugin-td5716243.html

To add any jars, easiest way is to use [Plugin Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: That did it for me! I removed some installed plugins and it worked. Thanks for the advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove all 3rd party plugins and install JMeter 3.0 instead of 2.11 which is now old.

http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

Comment: I tried installing Jmeter 3.0, even that gave me the same error, which plugins do i have to remove from Jmeter 3.0?

Comment: Jmeter 3 is not backward compatible to 2.11. If you move to version 3, you won't be able to go back to 2.11