# Not able to right click on JMeter elements

Tags: plugins, jmeter

Recently I downloaded a plugin - https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-ggl and since then I am not able to right click on any of the elements in the Jmeter GUI (v 5.2.1).
I tried the suggestion as below given in the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40152081/not-able-to-right-click-on-anything-on-jmeter) but it did not solve the issue.

1. Removed jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.4.jar from lib folder
2. Removed jmeter-plugins-graphs-ggl-2.0.jar from ext folder
3. Removed jmeter-plugins-manager-0.20.jar from ext folder

Please can someone help?

P.S: Plugins Manager gives me proxy Error on clicking because I am using my corporate proxy network. I download the jars and manually place them in the ext folder to use a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using JMeter 5.2.1 and Graphs Generator Listener 2.0, here is listing of my JMeter's "lib" folder:

```
C:\TEMP\APACHE-JMETER-5.2.1\LIB
│   accessors-smart-1.2.jar
│   apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar
│   asm-7.1.jar
│   bsf-2.4.0.jar
│   bsh-2.0b6.jar
│   bshclient.jar
│   caffeine-2.8.0.jar
│   checker-qual-2.10.0.jar
│   commons-codec-1.13.jar
│   commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
│   commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar
│   commons-io-2.6.jar
│   commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
│   commons-jexl3-3.1.jar
│   commons-lang3-3.9.jar
│   commons-logging-1.2.jar
│   commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
│   commons-net-3.6.jar
│   commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar
│   commons-text-1.8.jar
│   darcula-e208efb96f70e4be9dc362fbb46f6e181ef501dd.jar
│   dec-0.1.2.jar
│   dnsjava-2.1.9.jar
│   error_prone_annotations-2.3.3.jar
│   freemarker-2.3.29.jar
│   geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
│   groovy-all-2.4.16.jar
│   hamcrest-2.1.jar
│   hamcrest-core-2.1.jar
│   hamcrest-date-2.0.4.jar
│   httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar
│   httpclient-4.5.10.jar
│   httpcore-4.4.12.jar
│   httpcore-nio-4.4.12.jar
│   httpmime-4.5.10.jar
│   jackson-annotations-2.9.10.jar
│   jackson-core-2.9.10.jar
│   jackson-databind-2.9.10.jar
│   javax.activation-1.2.0.jar
│   jcharts-0.7.5.jar
│   jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.28.jar
│   jmespath-core-0.3.0.jar
│   jmespath-jackson-0.3.0.jar
│   jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.4.jar
│   jodd-core-5.0.13.jar
│   jodd-lagarto-5.0.13.jar
│   jodd-log-5.0.13.jar
│   jodd-props-5.0.13.jar
│   jorphan.jar
│   json-path-2.4.0.jar
│   json-smart-2.3.jar
│   jsoup-1.12.1.jar
│   jtidy-r938.jar
│   junit-4.12.jar
│   log4j-1.2-api-2.12.1.jar
│   log4j-api-2.12.1.jar
│   log4j-core-2.12.1.jar
│   log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar
│   mail-1.5.0-b01.jar
│   miglayout-core-5.2.jar
│   miglayout-swing-5.2.jar
│   mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar
│   neo4j-java-driver-1.7.5.jar
│   oro-2.0.8.jar
│   ph-commons-9.3.7.jar
│   ph-css-6.2.0.jar
│   rhino-1.7.11.jar
│   rsyntaxtextarea-3.0.4.jar
│   Saxon-HE-9.9.1-5.jar
│   serializer-2.7.2.jar
│   slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar
│   tika-core-1.22.jar
│   tika-parsers-1.22.jar
│   xalan-2.7.2.jar
│   xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar
│   xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
│   xmlgraphics-commons-2.3.jar
│   xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
│   xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
│   xstream-1.4.11.jar
│
├───ext
│       ApacheJMeter_bolt.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_components.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_core.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_ftp.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_functions.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_http.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_java.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_jms.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_junit.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_ldap.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_mail.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_mongodb.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_native.jar
│       ApacheJMeter_tcp.jar
│       jmeter-plugins-graphs-ggl-2.0.jar
│       jmeter-plugins-manager-0.20.jar
│       readme.txt
│
└───junit
        readme.txt
```

The listing was generated using [`tree /F apache-jmeter-5.2.1\lib`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree) command, inspect your own folder and make sure it's in sync with what's displayed above.

Normally the reason of any JMeter failure or at least a clue can be found in [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) so take a look there - most probably you will see what's causing the error.

With regards to the Plugins Manager - you should be able to use it behind the proxy, it respects [JMeter Proxy configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server), check out [Plugins Manager Network Configuration](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/)  chapter for more troubleshooting steps

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did check the logs and there were many errors including 1) JMeterTreeNode: getIcon(): Can't obtain GUI class from class org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet
2) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory
etc.,

Comment: And, starting the jmeter.bat with the proxy details gives me an error:
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxLiveObjectEvacuationRatio=20'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
errorlevel=1

I checked the bat file and I dont see MaxLiveObjectEvacuationRatio being mentioned; I have java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)